# set loadbalancing to true round-robin

Tags: kubernetes

What is the default behaviour when a kubernetes service is called over and over from the same clientip? I ran some tests and it seems that always the same pod is called and after a while it switches and then that pod gets called every time. Is that correct?

How can we setup kubernetes that every time a service is called it switches to the next pod?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working by using ip virtual server.

It's a service/module which hands out ip's of the next pod to schedule/call

it's likely installed already.

```
lsmod | grep ip_vs
ip_vs_sh               16384  0
ip_vs_wrr              16384  0
ip_vs_rr               16384  19
```

Have your cni properly setup and edit kube-proxy's ConfigMap

```
kubectl edit cm -n kube-system kube-proxy
```

edit the ipvs section

set mode to ipvs

```
mode: "ipvs"
```

and the ipvs section

```
ipvs:
      excludeCIDRs: null
      minSyncPeriod: 0s
      scheduler: "rr"
```

As always there are lots of variables biting each other with k8s, but it is possible with ipvs.

https://kubernetes.io/blog/2018/07/09/ipvs-based-in-cluster-load-balancing-deep-dive/